# Vue: All GmapInfoWindows open when one is clicked

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps

I am making a website where you can report crimes/incidents by placing a marker on a map and then the markers with all the incidents show on a different map.

Every marker has an info window that shows the incident and the time it was reported.

The problem I am having is that when I click one of the markers to open its info window, all of the info windows open.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <GmapMap
      ref="mapRef"
      :center="{ lat: 10, lng: 10 }"
      :zoom="11"
      style="width: 500px; height: 300px"
    >
      <GmapMarker
        :key="index"
        v-for="(m, index) in this.markers"
        :position="m.position"
        :clickable="true"
        @click="openWindow"
      >
        <GmapInfoWindow
          :opened="window_open"
          :position="m.position"
        >
          Incident: {{ m.incident }}<br />
          Time: {{ m.time }}
        </GmapInfoWindow>
      </GmapMarker>
    </GmapMap>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { gmapApi } from "vue2-google-maps";
import { db } from "../main";
export default {
  name: "MapComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      markerCollection: [],
      markers: [],
      info_marker: null,
      window_open: false,
    };
  },
  firestore() {
    return { markers: db.collection("Reports") };
  },

  methods: {
    openWindow() {
      if (this.window_open) {
        this.window_open = false;
      } else {
        this.window_open = true;
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    // At this point, the child GmapMap has been mounted, but
    // its map has not been initialized.
    // Therefore we need to write mapRef.$mapPromise.then(() => ...)

    this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
      map.panTo({ lat: 10, lng: 10 });
    });
  },
  computed: {
    google: gmapApi,
  },
};
</script>
```

I've seen some people's code that use GmapInfoWindows but they all just have one each, and didn't express any problems with it. And I have tried their code and I get this issue. I have also tried a lot of other things with the bools.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all of your `GmapInfoWindow` are attached to one flag condition: `window_open`.

So if you change `window_open` to `true`, all of them gets to show.

One way to fix that would be:

1. Modify `openWindow` method to:

```
openWindow(index) {
  this.window_open = this.window_open === index ? null : index;
},
```

2. Change you `opened` prop from `:opened="window_open"` to `:opened="window_open === index"`
3. Call your `openWindow` method with `openWindow(index)`.
4. I am suggesting changing the name `openWindow` to `toggleWindow` since you are not only showing it but hiding too.

Comment: This helped. I just added so when the reports come in, they have a bool named `window_open` attached to them which is false by default, and when they're clicked it only displays the selected marker.

Comment: @Boopiester I don't think your Backend should be involved in what is displayed on a Frontend. You are keeping additional info in database which is totally unnecessary. But anyway that's just a suggestion  Good luck!

Comment: I used your edited suggestion and it works great. Now it won't clutter up the database either. Thanks!